# How would i go about filling a triangle made by connecting 3 points

Tags: java, swing, awt

im interested i just finished writing a program and one of the functions that has been implemented is drawing a line with a triangle at the end (forming an arrow). How would i go about filling the inside of the triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [fillPolygon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon%28java.awt.Polygon%29) method of the `Graphics` class. There's also a version that doesn't require you to make a Polygon, instead accepting arrays with the coordinates. If you've been drawing the lines separately until now instead of as a polygon, it shouldn't be too hard to switch to one of these methods. Just use the endpoint coordinates you've already got.

Answer (score 1):

In a paint method, call [`Graphics.fillPolygon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29), or use [`Graphics2D.fill(Shape)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29).